# How to work with "React Material timeline onClick Collapse"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with timeline concept so my requirement is when I click on the particular timeline text that related data only should collapse and in my scenario the collapse logic is not working as per my requirement and below is my entire code

Import:

```
import React from "react";
//import UpdatesInfo from '../styled';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import ArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import ExpandLessIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';


import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';
import TimelineOppositeContent, {
    timelineOppositeContentClasses,
} from '@mui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';

import { Breadcrumbs, Container, Grid, Link, Typography, Box } from "@mui/material";
```

Like service data:

```
const updatesList = [

    {
        Sno: 1,
        Title: "2023",
        date: "",
        Content: "",
        Status: "true",

    },
    {
        Sno: 2,
        Title: "\"EXCEL\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-06-02",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with EXCEL. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"EXCEL\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",

    },
    {
        Sno: 3,
        Title: "\"NUVAMA\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-05-07",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
    {
        Sno: 4,
        Title: "\"SHAREKHAN\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2022-04-11",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
        month: "june",

    },
];

const updatesList_ = [

    {
        Sno: 5,
        Title: "2022",
        date: "",
        Content: "",
        Status: "true",

    },
    {
        Sno: 6,
        Title: "\"EXCEL...\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-06-02",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with EXCEL. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"EXCEL\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",

    },
    {
        Sno: 7,
        Title: "\"NUVAMA...\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-05-07",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
    {
        Sno: 8,
        Title: "\"SHAREKHAN...\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2022-04-11",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
        month: "june",

    },
];

const yearArr = [
    { "year": "2023", "data": updatesList },
    { "year": "2022", "data": updatesList_ }
];
```

Function Logic:

```
function MaeUpdates() {

    let length_ = updatesList.length;
    let date_ = ""
    let monthInMMMFormat_ = "";
    let dayindate_ = "";
    let formattedDay_ = "";
    let yearindate_ = "";

    let currdate = new Date();
    let curryear_ = currdate.getFullYear();
    //console.log(curryear_);

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
    const [year, setYear] = React.useState(curryear_);

    const handleClick = (id,year) => {
        setOpen(!open);
        setYear(year);

        console.log(open);
        //console.log(id);
        console.log(year);
        
    };

    //console.log(lnt);

    return (

        <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <Typography variant="h5">Updates</Typography>
            <Breadcrumbs separator="›" aria-label="breadcrumbs">
                <Link underline="hover" color="inherit" href="/">
                    <HomeIcon sx={{ mr: 0 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                </Link>
                <Link underline="hover" color="inherit" href="/">
                    About
                </Link>
                <Typography sx={{ color: hexacolorBC }}>Updates</Typography>
            </Breadcrumbs>

            <Grid container>

                <Grid item sx={12} md={12}>

                    <Typography sx={{ p: 4, fontSize: "14px", color: "#555555" }}>Latest updates on Modern Algos Platform. Stay updated with the latest features and use them immediately.</Typography>

                    {yearArr.map((arydata, index) => (

                        <Timeline
                            sx={{
                                [`& .${timelineOppositeContentClasses.root}`]: {
                                    flex: 0.1,
                                },
                            }}
                        >
                            {arydata.data.map((list, index) => (

                                //console.log(index),

                                date_ = new Date(list.date),
                                monthInMMMFormat_ = date_.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' }),
                                dayindate_ = date_.getDate(),
                                formattedDay_ = String(dayindate_).padStart(2, '0'),
                                yearindate_ = date_.getFullYear(),

                                //{if(index == 0) && <Typography></Typography>}

                                //<Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>

                                <TimelineItem>

                                    <TimelineOppositeContent sx={{ paddingTop: "0px" }} color='textSecondary'>
                                        {list.date != "" && <Typography sx={{ height: "50px", width: "50px", position: "relative", marginLeft: "25px", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#E5E5E5", borderStyle: "solid", borderRadius: "10px" }}>
                                            <ArrowRightIcon sx={{ position: "absolute", right: "-13px", top: "8px", color: "#034782" }} />
                                            <Typography sx={{ backgroundColor: "#034782", borderTopLeftRadius: "10px", borderTopRightRadius: "10px", color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>
                                                {monthInMMMFormat_}
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                                                {formattedDay_}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Typography>}

                                    </TimelineOppositeContent>
                                    <TimelineSeparator sx={{ p: 0, m: 0, paddingTop: "0px" }}>
                                        <TimelineDot sx={{ backgroundColor: "#034782" }} />
                                        {index != length_ - 1 && <TimelineConnector sx={{ backgroundColor: "#034782" }} />}
                                    </TimelineSeparator>
                                    <TimelineContent>

                                        {list.date == "" ? <Box onClick={()=>handleClick(0,arydata.year)} sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}><Typography sx={{ color: "#23B24D", position: "relative", fontSize: "16px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                                            {list.Title}
                                            {/* <ExpandMoreIcon sx={{position:"absolute"}}/> */}
                                            {open ? <ExpandMoreIcon sx={{ position: "absolute" }} /> : <ExpandLessIcon sx={{ position: "absolute" }} />}
                                        </Typography> </Box> : <Typography sx={{ color: "#034782", fontSize: "16px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                                            {list.Title}
                                        </Typography>}


                                            <Collapse in={open && year == arydata.year} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>

                                                <Typography sx={{ color: "#6D6D6D", fontSize: "14px", paddingBottom: 6 }}>
                                                    {list.Content}
                                                </Typography>

                                            </Collapse>

                                        {/* <Typography sx={{color:"#6D6D6D",fontSize:"14px",paddingBottom:6}}>
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            </Typography> */}
                                        {(index != 0 && index != length_ - 1) && <Typography sx={{ borderTop: "1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.3)", paddingBottom: 6, flexGrow: 1, marginRight: "10px" }}></Typography>}

                                    </TimelineContent>


                                </TimelineItem>


                                //</Collapse>

                            ))}

                        </Timeline>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default MaeUpdates;
```

I'm not sure where I did the mistake and please suggest me how to achieve this.
I'm very new to reacjs.